# Spring: default value for array property

Tags: java, spring

I have a bean defined like this:

```
@Component
class MapKeysFilter {

    @Value("${system.status.json.filter:}")
    private String[] filters;
```

When I start my application I expect the 'filters' field to be an empty array in case the 'system.status.json.filter' property is not set. However I'm getting an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'system.status.json.filter' in value "${system.status.json.filter}"
```

Can anybody please explain me why is it working like this?

N.B. I have another property injected in a similar way into the class marked with `@Configuration` and it works just fine. I'm using Spring 5.0.7.

Comment: How is `system.status.json.filter` defined?

Comment: I just put it to application.yml just like this:
`system.status.json.filter: ^spring.*,^.*\.request\.url$`
But if the property is not there I'm getting the exception, which is not completely what I expect to see.

Comment: This should work as intended. Do you missing your colon in actual code?

Comment: @Mạnh Quyết Nguyễn nope, I'm putting the default value after colon, i.e. empty array. The problem is, whatever I put after colon, I'm still getting the exception. I'm wondering why does it work like this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this :

```
@Value("${system.status.json.filter:}")
private String[] filters = new String[0];
```

Using a `List` insteand of an `Array` would enable you to do :

```
@Value("${system.status.json.filter:}#{T(java.util.Collections).emptyList()}")
private List<String> filters;
```

If you want to specfiy default non null values, add them separated by a comma .

For exemple :

```
@Value("${system.status.json.filter:oneFilter,anotherOne}")
private String[] filters ;
```

Comment: I tried initializing the array with `new String[0]` but it doesn't change anything, I'm still getting the same exception. Of course I can use List with SpEL like you shown, but I'm wondering why am I getting the exception if the property is not defined?

Comment: If you set a non-null value (just for the test), is the property resolved ?

Comment: I tried `@Value("${system.status.json.filter:test}")` but still got the  same exception

Comment: No, I was thinking of setting the value in the `.properties` file.

Comment: also, I tried List<String> with the SpEL like you shown and the exception is still being thrown

Comment: This is strange, I've tried all the solutions, and all of them are working. Are you using Spring Boot ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176855/discussion-between-timofey-and-thoomas).

Answer (score 2):

The error message is unrelated to your code. In the `MapKeysFilter` the Spring expression is `${system.status.json.filter:}` while the exception complains about  `${system.status.json.filter}`. Notice lack of colon `:` character, most likely the exception is thrown from some other place.

The correct syntax for injecting `null` with SpringEL is:

```
@Value("${system.status.json.filter:#{null}}")
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I'm still getting the same exception.
Also it doesn't explain why does the default value for the missing property injected correctly in the `@Configuration` class

Comment: @timofey where else are you using `system.status.json.filter` in your code?

Comment: that's the only place